# ToolBar OverflowPanel remains open

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I have a `ToolBar` with a `ItemsTemplate` which works fine until the `OverflowPanel` is Available.
The `OverflowPanel` does not close if i select one of the context actions.

The Problem only occurs if the Items are added via the `ItemsSource` binding:

```
     <ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding ContextActionViewModels}"
             Background="Transparent"
             ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True"
             FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False">
        <ToolBar.ItemTemplateSelector>
            <views:ContextActionTemplateSelector>
                <views:ContextActionTemplateSelector.SimpleContextActionDataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SimpleContextActionViewModel}">
                        <Button Name="Button"
                                Command="{Binding ActionCommand}"
                                Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonStyle}"
                                ToolTip="{userInterface:Translation Binding={Binding ToolTip}}">
                            <ContentControl Template="{Binding Icon,Converter={StaticResource NameToResourceConverter}}"
                                            Margin="5"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </views:ContextActionTemplateSelector.SimpleContextActionDataTemplate>

   <!-- Multiple DataTemplates follow!-->
```

Why is the `DataTemplate` / `ItemTemplteSelector` not working properly. While hardcoded Buttons in XAML work properly?

I uploaded a full sample that illustrates what is not working [here](http://www.filedropper.com/wpfapplication4):
Just Resize the window and try invoking one off the buttons in the `OverflowPanel`. While the 'ICommand' is executed properly the Popup stays open.

Comment: Hi, I've downloaded your app, but seems to be working fine for me. but I'm a bit puzzled with your code posted. What are you trying to achieve ? What is the ItemTemplateSelector for? if you want to have a separated display per datatype, just add the Datatemplate to the window resources and provide a type. No need to specify anything with  a selector.

Comment: @MartinMoser If you click a Button on the OverflowPanel (the dropdown popup) the Popup is closed properly? The ItemTemplateSelector does not cause any problems. It does not matter where i specify the DataTemplate. I still can not get it working.

Answer (score 1):

In the [.NET framework source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ToolBar.cs,dcc22f070b287f27) you can find the method that handles the closing behavior of `OverflowPanel` for `ToolBar` class:

```
private static void _OnClick(object e, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    ToolBar toolBar = (ToolBar)e;
    ButtonBase bb = args.OriginalSource as ButtonBase;
    if (toolBar.IsOverflowOpen && bb != null && bb.Parent == toolBar)
        toolBar.Close();
}
```

When you define a `DataTemplate` and use `ItemsSource` property, the `Parent` property of the created button becomes null and the if check fails. This is the expected behavior of `DataTemplate` as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> For templates, the Parent of the template eventually will be null. To get past this point and extend into the logical tree where the template is actually applied, use TemplatedParent.

As a solution you can set the `IsOverflowOpen` property to false when you click any of the buttons:

```
<ToolBar Name="SomeToolBar" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:ItemViewModel">
            <Button Command="{Binding Command}" Content="{Binding Name}" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
</ToolBar>

private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SomeToolBar.IsOverflowOpen = false;
}
```